# Android: play notification sound from a server?

Tags: android, audio, notifications

I plan playing a sound which is on a server online, just when the user gets a notification (via GCM).
Local sounds work fine with
notification.sound = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/notification/ringer.mp3");

But if I want to play a **ONLINE-sound**, it will not work:
notification.sound = Uri.parse("http://www.MyServer.com/ringer.mp3");

Perhaps, it is a trick to play **NO notification-sound** and open an activity that plays my online-sound with "buildMediaPlayer" instead?

Comment: I would not recommend doing it this way.  What if the device does not have internet at the time of notification?

Comment: thanks for reply. I can handle this if I have one default sound for notification, if user has no internet at this time.

Comment: Anyone else? any tipps?